# How to avoid user setting both ends of sliderInput together in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a Shiny app with a SliderInput for years, and I want to avoid users choosing a range that starts and ends on the same value (i.e. choosing the same year as start and end of the slider). What can I do to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid `sliderInput()` values being the same, or being set one over the other, we can set an observer with `observeEvent()` that gets triggered by changing the input, then check if the difference of both points of the slider is equal to zero (i.e., the values are the same), and in that case, we can update the slider using `updateSliderInput()` so that the points move themselves apart by 1:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

    fluidRow(
      column(12,
             sliderInput("years", label = "Select a year",
                         min = 2000, 
                         max = 2023, 
                         ticks = FALSE,
                         sep = "",
                         value = c(2008, 2015)
             )
      )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  observeEvent(input$years, {
    if (input$years[2] - input$years[1] == 0) {
        showNotification("Date range should be wider")
        updateSliderInput(inputId = "years",
                          value = c(input$years[1]-1, input$years[2]+1)
        )
      }
  })
    
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```